# Не имею гражданства или гражданство?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Как правильно пишется, подскажите, пожалуйста?

*Гражданства другого государства не имею*.
Или:
*Гражданство другого государства не имею.*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **не имею гражданства.**

[Розенталь: Справочник. ГЛАВА XLV. УПРАВЛЕНИЕ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)

§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием.

При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в других – употребление винительного падежа, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их использование.

**Родительный падеж**, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение **подчеркнутого отрицания**, обычно употребляется при глаголах **иметь, получать, доставать** и т.п., которые в сочетании с частицей *не* приобретают значение полного отрицания, например: не имеет комнаты, не получил приказа, не достал билета, не приобрел нужных вещей.

**Пример**.

*Права и обязанности лиц, **не имеющих гражданства**, в системе медицинского страхования.* Закон о медицинском страховании граждан в Российской Федерации (1991).